# Elastic search document count passing array

Tags: elasticsearch, count, elasticsearch-java-api

i am new in ElasticSearch i want count document based on id but i want to pass array in id like "myId":[1,2,3,4,5]

for every id i want count number

Current input

```
GET /probedb_v1/probe/_count
{
 "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
       "myId": 1
     }
  }
}
```

Current output

```
{ "count": 6929,
 "_shards":{ "total": 1,
  "successful": 1,
  "failed": 0
}
}
```

What is input for my 
Required Output

```
{ "count": [6929,5222,65241,5241,6521],
 "_shards":{ "total": 1,
  "successful": 1,
  "failed": 0
}
}
```

also need code for elasticsearch java-api

Comment: The `_id` is unique per index and type combination. So counting `_id` doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes _id unique but i want on my columns(term)

Comment: you will have to use aggregates. even that will not give the output in your desired format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
GET /probedb_v1/probe/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "myId": [123, 44]
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myId",
        "size": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you this output:

```
   "aggregations": {
      "NAME": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 123,
               "doc_count": 3
            },
            {
               "key": 44,
               "doc_count": 2
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works but not as expected. I need separate outputs(count) for each input. I received this output. ** "hits": {"total": 2,} **

Comment: Your English is not that good and I don't understand what you mean. The output as `"count": [6929,5222,65241,5241,6521]` is not possible in Elasticsearch. The best approach is with aggregations and the output I provided in my answer.